# Can't print out sociable numbers properly

Tags: c

I have a code that finds the sum of the divisors of a number, but I can't get it to apply on my increasing n and print all the numbers respectively.
The code is

```
long div(int n) {
  long sum = 0;
  int square_root = sqrt(n);

  for (int i = 1; i <= square_root; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
        sum += i;
        if (i * i != n) {
            sum += n / i; 
        }
    }
  }

return sum - n;
}
```

On my main() I need to have a c number that starts from 1 and goes to my MAXCYC which is 28. The n goes from 2 to MAXNUM which is 10000000. The program needs to find all perfect, amicable and sociable numbers and print them with their respective pairs.
**Sample output:**
*Cycle of length 2: 12285 14595 12285

Cycle of length 5: 12496 14288 15472 14536 14264 12496*

```
for (int n = 2; n <= MAXNUM; n++) { 

    long sum = div(n);
    long res = div(sum);
    if (res <= MAXNUM) { // Checking if the number is just sociable
            int c = 0;

            while (c <= MAXCYC && n != res) {
                res = div(sum);
                c++;
            }
            if (c <= MAXCYC) {
                printf("Cycle of length %d: ", c);

                        printf("%ld ", sum);
                    do {
                        printf("%ld ", res);
                        res = div(res);
                    }
                    while (sum < res);

                printf("%ld ", sum);
                c += c - 2;
                printf("\n");
            }
    }
}
```

I only get pairs of cycle length of 1, 2 and nothing above that. Also it doesn't even print it correctly since it says Cycle of length 0: in all of the results without increasing. I think the problem is in the *f* before the first print but I can't get it to work in a way that as long as my
**(n == sum)** it prints *Cycle of length 1: x x pairs*
**(n == res && sum < res)** it prints *Cycle of length 2: x y x pairs*
**(res <= MAXNUM)** it prints *Cycle of length c: x y z ... x* (c amount of pairs including first x)

What do you guys think I should change?

Comment: What is the input to this program, if any?

Comment: @thecoder When you run it, it's supposed to start from the n = 2 and go all the way until it reaches n <= MAXNUM.

Comment: And print all cycles of any length until 28?

Comment: That's exactly sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this code should work if I understood well your requirement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int div_sum(int n)
{
    long sum = 0;
    int square_root = sqrt(n);

    for (int i = 1; i <= square_root; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            sum += i;
            if (i * i != n)
            {
                sum += n / i;
            }
        }
     }
    return sum - n;
}

int MAX_N = 10000000;
int MAX_CYCLES = 28;


int main()
{
    int cycles;
    for(int n = 2; n < MAX_N; n++){
       int found = 0;
       for(int c = 1; !found  && c <= MAX_CYCLES; c++){
           cycles = c;
           int aliquote = n;
           while(cycles--) aliquote = div_sum(aliquote);

           //it is a cycle of length c
           cycles = c;
           if(n == aliquote){
               printf("Cycle of length %d: %d", c, n);
               while(cycles--){
                   aliquote = div_sum(aliquote);
                   printf(" %d", aliquote);
               }
               printf("\n");
               found = 1;
           }
        }
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: It has similar problems with my code, it repeats some results: Cycle of length 5: 12496 14288 15472 14536 14264 12496
Cycle of length 5: 14264 12496 14288 15472 14536 14264.

Comment: Well, I saw that, but I left it as an exercise for you, it shouldn't be difficult ;) The important thing is that it solves the problem, you should just do this correction.

Comment: I tried changing *while(cycles--){* to **while(cycles-- && n < aliquote){** but I just get single asnwers now.

Comment: Hint: every number in the cycle should not be checked again. Every number that forms a cycle, don't use it as beginning of another sequence (the value of `n` in the loop). PS: You can also accept and up-vote the answer if it helped.

Comment: I upvoted but since I'm new on the site it said that it won't show on public and just keep it in records. I changed **n** to **a** from the line *printf("Cycle of length %d: %d", c, n);* to stop duplicates from cycles 1 and 2, but I still get them for above numbers.

Comment: You can accept the answer, it must show in public. Anyway, use one array `visited` to store each number you visited in some cycle , than for every `n` check if you `visited[n]`, in that case continue without processing `n`.

Comment: What if I can not use arrays?

Comment: Then there is no way to avoid repeating. You must **memorize** the sequences you did, if you don't want to repeat them.

Comment: The exercise says that we can't use arrays and on the given output there no repetitions.

Comment: Ok, then I think it maybe possible, if you make your cycles 'just' increasing. That is when you apply the sum you check if `n < div_sum(n)` then continue constructiong the sequence, otherwise stop, because if `n > div_sum(n)`, then we found this cycle already, when we started with  div_sum(n).

Comment: Wait, I don't use n < div_sum(n) in my code. Should I apply that when I'm checking if (n == a)?

Comment: Technically in every step check `if(aliquote <= div_sum(aliquote))`.

Comment: I tried setting n < a so that the numbers are printed in order and therefore this stops the repetition but with no effect. It still prints duplicates.

Comment: Ok, I think is not possible without storing the numbers you visited, you have to use array. Try to check the assignment.

Comment: I think if I can make each new div_sum(aliquote) be bigger than the previous this will stop the repetition. I know how to do that If I have multiple variables (let's say I had sum, sum2, sum3, I could do sum < sum 2 < sum3) but I don't know how to use it now that I only have 1 variable (aliquote).

Comment: If you have to find of length 28? 28 variables? :D

Comment: That's what I thought at first but it's wrong. Also that's the reason I used do while on my code, but again that's wrong. I pretty sure I need to use for (c = 1; c <=MAXCYC; c++) in order for the code to repeat itself as long as the c goes on, but I don't really know how I can make it that it prints as many numbers as c's and also avoid duplicates. On top of that I have to set 3 variables to count the amount of perfect, amicable and cycles respectively which I can only do if I have 3 different printfs about ("Cycle of length %d: ", c), which again I think is incorrect.