# C Program to calculate perfect, amicable and sociable numbers

Tags: c, perfect-numbers, sociable

I am using Dev **C++** and the program is running without errors. The problem that I have is that it repeats numbers from previous cycles and I have no effective way to calculate how many of those numbers are perfect, amicable or just sociable.
This is  the main program:

```
int main()
{
    int per = 0, cyc = 0, ami = 0, rep = 0;
    for(int n = 2; n < MAXNUM; n++){
        int f = 0;
        for(int c = 1; !f  && c <= MAXCYC; c++){
            rep = c;
            long a = n;
            while(rep--) a = divs(a);
            rep = c;

            if(n == a ){
                printf("Cycle of length %d: %d", c, n);
                while(rep --){
                    a = divs(a);
                    printf(" %ld", a);
                    cyc++;
                }
                printf("\n");
                f = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nFound %d cycles including \n", cyc);
    printf("%d cycles with perfect numbers and \n", per);
    printf("%d cycles with amicable numbers\n", ami);

    return 0;
}
```

How can I make it so it won't repeat numbers from previous cycles as starting points for new cycles while having my per and ami counters going up? Also I can't use arrays as I am not allowed to.

Comment: Any time I see the phrase *"running without errors"*, I assume that means *"has a ton of warnings that I'm ignoring"*. Hard to tell how many warnings there are because the definitions for `MAXNUM` and `MAXCYC` are missing, and the function `divs` is also missing. But there is a warning on the line `printf(" %d",a);` since `%d` expects an `int`, but `a` is a `long`.

Comment: I purposely didn't include the whole code in order to save up some space. Also I fixed the %ld part, thanks for noting that despite the fact that I didn't give me any errors before.

Comment: Note: continuation of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450093/cant-print-out-sociable-numbers-properly)

Comment: After looking at the other question: you need to abort the cycle check if any number in the cycle is smaller than the number that you started with.

Comment: @user3386109 Adding n < a doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Since nobody has posted an answer, you could update the code in the question with the changes that you made, and add an example of the problem that you are seeing.

Comment: Thats the problem in the code: Cycle of length 1: 8128 8128 Cycle of length 2: 10744 10856 10744 Cycle of length 2: 10856 10744 10856 Cycle of length 2: 12285 14595 12285 Cycle of length 5: 12496 14288 15472 14536 14264 12496 Cycle of length 5: 14264 12496 14288 15472 14536 14264. Sorry for the format, comments won't allow me to make it look more clear. It starts another cycle that's basically the previous one but starts from a different point.